# Any tips to reduce repetition when using Lua C functions

Tags: c, lua

I have a block of code that looks like this:

```
lua_newtable(L);

lua_pushstring(L, "gid");
lua_pushinteger(L, info[i].codepoint);
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_pushstring(L, "cl");
lua_pushinteger(L, info[i].cluster);
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_pushstring(L, "ax");
lua_pushnumber(L, pos[i].x_advance);
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_pushstring(L, "ay");
lua_pushnumber(L, pos[i].y_advance);
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_pushstring(L, "dx");
lua_pushnumber(L, pos[i].x_offset);
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_pushstring(L, "dy");
lua_pushnumber(L, pos[i].y_offset);
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_pushstring(L, "w");
lua_pushinteger(L, extents.width);
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_pushstring(L, "h");
lua_pushinteger(L, extents.height);
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_pushstring(L, "yb");
lua_pushinteger(L, extents.y_bearing);
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_pushstring(L, "xb");
lua_pushinteger(L, extents.x_bearing);
lua_settable(L, -3);
```

What I am doing is just setting a few fields inside a table. The fields are either strings or numbers. Note how repetitive the code is.

Is there a way to make this a bit cleaner, maybe using C macros?

Comment: This is in the context of Lua C functions. Maybe someone more experienced knows a trick of some kind that I am missing.

Comment: Use pointers, arrays and loops.

Comment: @this how about a small example?

Comment: @vyom Instead of hardcoding string literals and repeating the function calls for each one,  make an array of string literals and loop through it. `char* array[] = { "ab" , "cd" , "ef" };`

Comment: also try this:

#define lua_add_integer_field( L, value, name ) { \
    lua_pushinteger(L, value); \
    lua_setfield(L, -2, name); \
}

you can move the table index (-2) out of the macro. Sorry, dont know how to format this in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reduce the length by 1/3 by replacing

```
lua_pushstring(L, "cl");
lua_pushinteger(L, info[i].cluster);
lua_settable(L, -3);
```

by

```
lua_pushinteger(L, info[i].cluster);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "cl");
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you that is really useful. I missed that C function in the docs.

Comment: Is there a way to unify the `lua_pushinteger` and `lua_pushstring` calls as well, by any chance? I realise they are two different methods for two different types, but any sort of macro trick perhaps?

Comment: In theory you could define a function `set_integer_field` that receives the field name and field value. However, you would also need to define similar functions for other types, like  `set_string_field`, `set_boolean_field` and so on. I'm not sure this extra complexity would be worth the trouble...

Comment: @vyom I've added an example using generic macros to my answer.

Comment: @hugomg You are probably right, and I don’t have a lot of experience with C. The library I am writing may have a lot of these kinds of assignments, so I was considering something that would avoid a lot of verbose code.

Answer (score 3):

> maybe using C macros?

## More practical

With C11 generic macros, it gets simpler:

```
#define lua_push(L, X) _Generic((X), const char*: lua_pushstring, \
                                     float: lua_pushnumber, \
                                     int: lua_pushinteger)(L, X)
```

Then you can wrap it up in a `lua_setfield_generic`:

```
#define lua_setfield_generic(L, NAME, X) \
    lua_push(L, X); \
    lua_setfield(L, -2, NAME);
```

And here's how your code would look:

```
lua_setfield_generic(L, "gid", info[i].codepoint);
lua_setfield_generic(L, "cl", info[i].codepoint);
lua_setfield_generic(L, "ax", pos[i].x_advance);
```

## Less practical, but fancy

Since you're essentially marshaling data to Lua, it's best to make it more declarative and data based.

Imagine such a `struct` definition:

```
STRUCT(Point)
FIELD(x, float);
FIELD(y, float);
END_STRUCT
```

With some clever thinking, you can build a structure out of this and a function `PointToLuaTable` (To create a name you need `##`) that will pick appropriate types of lua functions and call them in order, taking the names from the names of fields (obtained via `#`).

You could take it even further. Craft your own preprocessor that uses e.g. Clang's API to parse your struct definitions and generate the appropriate functions, then as a 2nd build step use those files to build those functions.

That being said - *why* would you do that in C at all? It's not a language that's designed to do that. It lacks reflection and proper generics in order to make it worthwhile.

Comment: It wasn’t me (the downvoter). Thank you for your answer. The Generic macro seems useful. Although I am not sure how portable it is. I will read up more about C macros and then decide whether the additional complexity is worth it.

Comment: @vyom it's exactly as portable as C11 itself.

Comment: I suppose you are right. I have the `-std=c99` flag set in my Makefile. So I am not sure whether this code will generate a warning or error. I will try it.

Comment: @vyom you need to change it to `c11`

Comment: I know I need to change it, but I don’t wish to unless there is a good reason. I want the code to be as portable as possible. There might be environments where this code is used which might require stricter standards of portability. I don’t know for sure. That’s why I said, I will try it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96692/discussion-between-vyom-and-bartek-banachewicz).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the C preprocessor to apply a C macro to a list of tuples:

```
#define INFO_FIELDS( _ ) \
  _( codepoint, "gid", integer ) \
  _( cluster, "cl", integer )

#define POS_FIELDS( _ ) \
  _( x_advance, "ax", number ) \
  _( y_advance, "ay", number ) \
  _( x_offset, "dx", number ) \
  _( y_offset, "dy", number )

#define EXTENT_FIELDS( _ ) \
  _( width, "w", integer ) \
  _( height, "h", integer ) \
  _( y_bearing, "yb", integer ) \
  _( x_bearing, "xb", integer ) \


#define GEN( _m, _n, _t ) \
  (lua_push##_t( L, info[i]._m ), lua_setfield( L, -2, _n ));
INFO_FIELDS( GEN )
#undef GEN

#define GEN( _m, _n, _t ) \
  (lua_push##_t( L, pos[i]._m ), lua_setfield( L, -2, _n ));
POS_FIELDS( GEN )
#undef GEN

#define GEN( _m, _n, _t ) \
  (lua_push##_t( L, extents._m ), lua_setfield( L, -2, _n ));
EXTENT_FIELDS( GEN )
#undef GEN
```

I'm not sure it pays off in your case, but it shines if you can use the lists multiple times (e.g. to read values from the stack and assign them to struct fields, or to define the C structs in the first place).